# Json LatLong values to mapActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, arraylist, hashmap

i received lat and long values through Json and saved in ArrayList And then i passed this Array list to MapAcitivity

```
    matchFixture = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_FIXTURE);
                Log.d("json aray", "user point array");
                int len = matchFixture.length();
                Log.d("len", "get array length");
                for (int i = 0; i < matchFixture.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = matchFixture.getJSONObject(i);
                    String matchId = c.getString(TAG_Lat);
                    Log.d("matchId", matchId);
                    String teamA = c.getString(TAG_Lon);
                    Log.d("teamA", teamA);

                    //  hashmap for single match
                     matchFixtures = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    matchFixtures.put(TAG_Lat matchId);
                    matchFixtures.put(TAG_Long, teamA);

                    matchFixtureList.add(matchFixtures);
```

this is how i passed the values

```
Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = matchFixtures.keySet().iterator();
    while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
        String key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
        String value=(String)matchFixtures.get(key);
```

and this is how i recieved in map acitivity

```
HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) getIntent().getExtras().get("hashMapKey");

    Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = hm.keySet().iterator();
    while (myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) myVeryOwnIterator.next();
        String value = (String) hm.get(key);
        for (int i = 0; i <=1; i++){}
```

but now i dont have any idea how to get these values in such order that fits specific latlog to show places on map its basically for  multiple markers on maps

Comment: I'd create a model class for it and pass a list of model classes instead of putting them in a hashmap. That makes code more readable. Anyways, what do you mean by "in such order that fits specific latlog" ?

Comment: for example arraylist has 2 lat and to 2 longtute one show my home and one on university so i want to receive  both in order to show these places

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use a model class for this.

```
class Model {
    public float homeLat;
    public float homeLng;
    public float universityLat;
    public float universityLng;
}
```

You can create an object of a model class for each of the entry and put it in a list.

```
Model model = new Model();
model.homeLat = <The Value from Json>
...
matchFixtureList.add(model);
```

and then in your activity when you read the list values you can get specific lat and long to show a marker.